# SQL Server Express edition keeps refusing me access when I'm at work or at home?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, installation, instance

I have a paid for SQL Server 2008 R2 already installed and the network server is somewhere on this globe (Be great if someone could tell me how to find the name of it?) and also at work we have our own Domain Server, which I can connect to via VPN at home. (Before anyone says this again, yes I know I can install express on a different machine but part of my internship is learning this, there's no way I'm carrying two laptops, have you commuted through London? Wearing a swim suit could make you too big to get on a tube.)

The Deal:
I downloaded sequel server again, by default already, but to double check, it was a 'Named Instance' such as SQLexpress1 and I gave it 'Windows Authentication. I created a bunch of local users (Guided From tutorials but there was mention about not being in a DOMAIN) as I'm hoping to turn my machine into the local server as I don't want this instance connecting to any network. I just want to have the database saved on my laptop and open it up in ssms and start going Chuck Norris with code.

The Problem:
I open up ssms, log in using the server name like "UKLONN10532\SQLEXPRESS2" all great. I can attach a sample database but when I log out and go home and access my database I get this error, text down below. Even when I log into VPN and in my own domain is doesn't work, and even if I go back into work it still doesn't work, it seems broken permanently. I've done re-installations 4 times, every time I can create an instance, log in and out fine when at work or home, but when I access at another location it doesn't work (Btw I attempted this at home with all internet off and it worked at home and at work for two days then suddenly stopped giving me access but I might have been hibernating my machine, not sure) so it seems that however I install it, if I cross over from work to home and vice versa, a problem arises.

I just want another SQL Server unrelated to work or any network as the database will be saved in my C: drive so I need my machine to act like it is the server. I simply want a database I can apply my learning to but it seems that using the same SSMS for two databases is conflicting.

Many Thanks,

**Error Statment**

> Cannot connect to UKLONN10532\SQLEXPRESS2. Additional Information: A
>   network related or instance specific error occurred while establishing
>   a connection to sql server. The server was not found or was not
>   accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that sql
>   server is configured to allow remote connections. (Provider : SQL
>   Network interfaces, error: 26 – error locating server/instance
>   specified)(Microsoft sql server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off guess check your SQL Server Configuration Manager and make sure that your instance is up and running.  Here is a link where Pinal Dave talks about a similar error and goes through in detail how to check to make sure the instance is up and a number of other troubleshooting steps you should try.
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

Comment: Looks good, I have done some of these already but nothing had everything compiled into one article. Be good to do this and rule out possible errors. But my question is that I can't access my database, so SQL Server configuration Manager will show this as "stopped" regardless? Some of these procedures require me to be in SSMS on my instance. I did have access before but relocating to another a different network has altered something o.O

Comment: Try using a sql server login rather than a domain login.  And no, your instance could certainly be running and you still not be able to access it.  It's just the first thing to test.  Also making sure that SQL Server Browser is running if you are connecting remotely.

Comment: Kenneth you are a genius! You've inadvertently solved my problem, your comment "And no, your instance could certainly be running and you still not be able to access it. It's just the first thing to test." was the key, I've simply gone onto SQL Manager and changed the sql server to log on as "Local system" and it's running and it opens up in SSMS. I made 5 local user accounts before installing, in the Local Users and Groups Microsoft Management Console (MMC) such as.\SQLEngine, .\SQLReporting etc... And assigned each SQL Server component to it, something about this and being in my work domain?

Comment: For a local install on a workstation .. just a playground right? .. I wouldn't use user accounts unless you are testing that specifically.  Just set everything to LocalSystem or NT Authority\Network Service.

Comment: I don't fully understand but if you could explain what went wrong that would be great so I can learn from my ways. Each component was given a name and a password (That never expires) and I used these when installing my instance. Each group is a member of "Users are prevented from making accidental or intentional system-wide changes and can run most" I don't understand the difference now since I changed it to "local system"? I assumed that it was already using my machine as such. All guesses are welcome and thanks again!

Comment: Sorry Kenneth run out of characters, yes just something to play with and practice my sql.

Comment: It's more a matter of ease.  For a local playground there just isn't a good reason to create local users.  Try looking in the error log to see if you were getting a specific problem when using your local users/groups as startup accounts.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server *does* allow you to log in with cached domain credentials (ie. when no domain controller is available to validate the login). I use the scenario you mentioned countless times. What I can tel right away about your setup is that `UKLONN10532\SQLEXPRESS2` is a different **machine** than `UK10532\SQLEXPRESS2`. So, which one is actually your laptop? It seems you're trying to connect to a different machine.

Comment: Apologies Remus, but indeed you have a sharp eye! Since I'm new to stackoverflow I don't have enough points to attach images yet. The correct setup is UKLONN10532\SQLEXPRESS2 and this was displayed in the error message as well. Simple typo, will re -edit